# Get window height and set div sizes to this height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to set div sizes to the size of browser window on open.

I am using this to get the window height..

```
    var height = window.innerHeight
    || document.documentElement.clientHeight
    || document.body.clientHeight;
```

but now I am stuck as to how i can pass this height into the html..

The div I want to resize has a lot of content inside so I don't think I can   simply use replaceWith() and put the new height css inline as i need to also pass in all the other html which will be a big pain.

If you can answer in both js and/or jQ it would be fantastic.

Thank you

Comment: Ok so we may need to see a bit of your code because I don't see why you would need to do it in js. Simply do it in css ... no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d0ufr8hx/

HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

    $('div').height(height)
});
```

Alternatively, use a pure CSS solution (`vh` and `vw`):

```
div {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Be cautious of `vh` and `vw` if you are trying to support older browsers,
 for instance neither are supported beyond IE 11. [Browser support for `vh`](https://caniuse.com/#search=vh), [browser support for `vw`](https://caniuse.com/#search=vh).

Answer (score 3):

The dimensional units 'vh' and 'vw' were added to CSS3 to do this sort of thing.  Setting the height to 100vh should do what you want.

Comment: To expand on this just a little, "vh" and "vw" stand for viewport height and viewport width respectively. Each unit represents a percent (1/100) of the current viewport size, so 100vh == 100% of the viewport's current height. The sizes are recalculated if the viewport changes size, so the div would always be 100% of the viewport's height even if you resize the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

So according to your pure javaScript code You can Try this : -

```
 <div id="divId"></div>

document.getElementById('divId').style.height = height +"px"
```